# What is the correct condition of the if statement in php blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to compare the value from my database by accessing foreach loop to a given string 'allowance' and the value of `$scholar->scholarship_name` in database is allowance also. So, it suppose to be true but I've got the error below...

Here is the error  :

> syntax error, unexpected '<'

Here is the code:

```
@foreach($scholars as $scholar)
{!! $scholar->sponsor_name !!}
{!! $scholar->scholarship_name !!}
11-7-2014
@if (  {!! $scholar->scholarship_name !!} == 'allowance')
I have one record!
@else
I don't have any records!
@endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: `@if ($scholar->scholarship_name == 'allowance')`

Comment: I try it but the result is always false even it's true

Comment: Clearly not.... try var_dumping `$scholar->scholarship_name` to see what it really contains

Answer (score 0):

When you use the @ blade syntax, you're already in the PHP parser. You don't need to escape your variables.

```
@if ( $scholar->scholarship_name == 'allowance')
```